# How To Use JWT Tokens to Authenticate Website Users for FireBase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am building a mobile app that uses firebase. When logging in, I would like for the application to authenticate users from my website database then copy that information to the firebase database. Upon creating a account, it should write to the website database, then to the firebase database.

Right now I feel a little stuck in the mud, im not sure if im moving in the right direction or if I should completely start over and approach this from another angle so to speak. Right now the following error is stumping me, I dont know where this key is supposed to come from:

```
undefined
/codestudio/firebasesdk.js:40
    var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicKey' of undefined
    at /codestudio/firebasesdk.js:40:26
    at /codestudio/node_modules/lru-memoizer/index.js:81:20
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /codestudio/node_modules/lru-memoizer/index.js:77:17
    at /codestudio/node_modules/jwks-rsa/lib/wrappers/cache.js:22:18
    at /codestudio/node_modules/jwks-rsa/lib/JwksClient.js:51:18
    at /codestudio/node_modules/jwks-rsa/lib/JwksClient.js:104:18
    at Request._callback (/home/ethreil/Desktop/codestudio/node_modules/jwks-rsa/lib/JwksClient.js:88:20)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/ethreil/Desktop/codestudio/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
```

MY CODE

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var refreshToken; // Get refresh token from OAuth2 flow

var serviceAccount = require('/home/ethreil/Desktop/codestudio/ggbsdk.json');
var uid = "some-uid";


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://goodgamebuzz.firebaseio.com'

});

var fs = require('fs');
var cert = fs.readFileSync('/home/ethreil/Desktop/codestudio/privateKey.pem');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var token = jwt.sign({ 
  expiresIn: 36000 ,
  audience: "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit" ,
  issuer: 'myserviceaccount@gmail.com' ,
  subject: 'myservicecaccount@gmail.com' ,
  iat: Math.floor(Date.now()) 
 } ,
 cert
  ,
 {
  algorithm: 'RS256' ,
  keyid: '7a3d1904f18e257948831eab803e12b7971e13ab' 
});

const kid = '7a3d1904f18e257948831eab803e12b7971e13ab';
var jwksClient = require('jwks-rsa');
var client = jwksClient({
  cache:true ,
  jwksUri: 'https://goodgamebuzz.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate'
});

client.getSigningKey(kid, function(err, key) {
    var signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
    callback(null, signingKey);
  });


jwt.verify(token, cert, {
   algorithms: 'RS256' ,
   audience: 'goodgamebuzz' ,
   issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/goodgamebuzz" ,
   subject: uid 
  
} ,
  function(err, decoded) {
  console.log(decoded) // bar
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using a callback when getting the signing key?

As per the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa:

```
const kid = '<some kid>';
const key = await client.getSigningKey(kid);
const signingKey = key.getPublicKey();
```